# i have been trying to install expo-cli for some days but still couldnt figure out what going wrong

Tags: reactjs, npm, expo, native

I have been trying to get expo working but I have no idea what I'm doing wrong. I have tried:

`npm install expo-cli`

I have been trying for 1 week all different kind of ways but nothing is working.

```
npm WARN deprecated @hapi/joi@17.1.1: Switch to 'npm install joi'
npm WARN deprecated xmldom@0.1.31: Deprecated due to CVE-2021-21366 resolved in 0.5.0
npm WARN deprecated @hapi/formula@2.0.0: Moved to 'npm install @sideway/formula'
npm WARN deprecated @hapi/pinpoint@2.0.0: Moved to 'npm install @sideway/pinpoint'
npm WARN deprecated @hapi/address@4.1.0: Moved to 'npm install @sideway/address'
npm WARN deprecated core-js@2.6.12: core-js@<3 is no longer maintained and not recommended for usage due to the number of issues. Please, upgrade your dependencies to the actual version of core-js@3.
npm WARN deprecated request@2.88.2: request has been deprecated, see https://github.com/request/request/issues/3142
npm WARN deprecated har-validator@5.1.5: this library is no longer supported
npm WARN deprecated urix@0.1.0: Please see https://github.com/lydell/urix#deprecated
npm WARN deprecated resolve-url@0.2.1: https://github.com/lydell/resolve-url#deprecated
npm WARN deprecated xmldom@0.1.27: Deprecated due to CVE-2021-21366 resolved in 0.5.0
npm WARN deprecated chokidar@2.1.8: Chokidar 2 will break on node v14+. Upgrade to chokidar 3 with 15x less dependencies.
npm WARN deprecated fsevents@1.2.13: fsevents 1 will break on node v14+ and could be using insecure binaries. Upgrade to fsevents 2....
```

Answer (score 0):

I work on Expo. You are seeing warnings but as far as I can tell those don't actually prevent installation.

Here's the usual response we have to questions about this:

> We resolve npm warnings whenever we can, and usually this means upgrading or switching dependencies, but we don't always have control over this. Sometimes a package has moved to a new name and made breaking changes at the same time, for example dropping support for a specific Node version that we support in expo-cli. Usually the warnings you see are from distant downstream dependencies, eg: expo-cli depends on package `a` which depends on `x` which depends on `y` which depends on `z`. we have to wait for `a` to update their dependency on `x` which results in updating `y` and `z`.
>
> Basically every non-trivial package in the Node ecosystem will come with messages like this on install due to the unfortunate way that unactionable warnings are exposed to users. Some tools use `ncc` to vendor the dependencies, which essentially hides the warnings but the underlying code is basically the same.
>
> We update dependencies whenever it makes sense to, and we do that frequently. These warnings will not interfere with your usage of expo-cli :)